# AWSにて、CentOS7をc4からc5にインスタンスタイプを変更する

Tags: centos, aws

Rightscaleで管理をしているCentOS7のインスタンスタイプを
c4からc5へ変更したところ、インスタンスチェックに失敗し、
SSH接続することができません。

・試してみたコマンド

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel -y install kernel-ml
rpm -qa | grep "^kernel" | sort
```

---

```
[root@c5upTEST ~]# rpm -qa | grep "^kernel" | sort
kernel-ml-4.19.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
kernel-plus-3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-plus-devel-3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-plus-devel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-plus-headers-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
```

---

```
[root@c5upTEST ~]# awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
0 : CentOS Linux (4.19.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) 7 (Core)
1 : CentOS Linux (3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.centos.plus.x86_64) 7 (Core)
2 : CentOS Linux (3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.centos.plus.x86_64) 7 (Core)
3 : CentOS
```

---

```
[root@c5upTEST ~]# grub2-set-default 0
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-editenv list
```

---

```
[root@c5upTEST ~]# uname -a
Linux c5upTEST.xxxx.jp 4.19.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 22 10:40:32 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
modinfo ena
OK!!!
```

// ENA サポート設定

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --ena-support
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].EnaSupport' --region ap-northeast-1 --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

SSH接続できるようにしたいのですが、なにかお分かりになる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: 「接続できない」と判断した情報、例えばSSHでの接続時に「○○とエラーメッセージが表示された」などのより詳しい情報があるとアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。 / 色々試されているようですが、kernel周りの情報は何を確認する目的で載せた情報なのかがイマイチ分かりません。直接のログイン？が出来ているのならsshdのログなどを確認された方がよいのかなと。

Comment: ブートはしてるけど、NICがアップしてなさそうですね。C5用のドライバが入っているかと、ENAが有効になってないのかなと 推測します。`modinfo ena`  の結果と、`aws ec2 describe-instances...` の結果が質問に書かれてないので追記してもらえますか？ `ethtool -i eth0` の結果もお願いします。eth0 のところはお使いのネットワークデバイスの名前に読み替えてください。